# How to setup datastructure so to make pandas and numpy co-operate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Having troubles compiling code that is based on pandas and numpy. I will try to explaining the issues by providing a downscaled working examples of where the problem lies.

What I'm basically trying to do is Markowitz portfolio optimization, in the following way.

First I have a pandas.Dataframe that has closing prices for given ticker in the following way.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['AAPL'] = [1.2,1.4,1.5]
df['GOOGL'] = [2.1,2.4,2.6]
df['DATE'] = ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02','2017-01-03']
df = df.set_index('DATE')
```

Next I want to create some basic statistics to pass the in some functions, which I do in the following way:

```
returns = df.pct_change()
mean_returns = returns.mean()
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
num_portfolios = 10
risk_free_rate = 0.0178
```

The type of these statistics is of:

```
pandas.core.series.Series
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

The following functions are where the problems start to arise:

```
def portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    returns = np.sum(mean_returns*weights ) *252
    std = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
    return std, returns

def random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    results = np.zeros((3,num_portfolios))
    print('results:',type(results))
    weights_record = []
    for i in range(num_portfolios):
        weights = np.random.random(12)
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        weights_record.append(weights)
        portfolio_std_dev, portfolio_return = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        results[1,i] = portfolio_return
        results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
    #print('results[2,0]:',type(results[2,0]))
    #print('std', type(portfolio_std_dev))
    #print(portfolio_return)
    return results, weights_record


def display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate):
    results, weights = random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)


    max_sharpe_idx = np.argmax(np.array(results[2]))
    sdp, rp = results[0,max_sharpe_idx], results[1,max_sharpe_idx]
    max_sharpe_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[max_sharpe_idx],index=df.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    max_sharpe_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in max_sharpe_allocation.allocation]
    max_sharpe_allocation = max_sharpe_allocation.T

    min_vol_idx = np.argmin(results[0])
    sdp_min, rp_min = results[0,min_vol_idx], results[1,min_vol_idx]
    min_vol_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[min_vol_idx],index=df.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    min_vol_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in min_vol_allocation.allocation]
    min_vol_allocation = min_vol_allocation.T
```

When trying to run:

display_simulated_ef_with_random(cov_matrix, mean_returns, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate)

The following error appears

```
----> 2     results, weights = random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)

---> 15         results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: What version of python, pandas, numpy are you using? This works with no errors for me (after changing size of weights to `weights = np.random.random(2)`, since you only provide 2 assets)

Comment: I'm using numpy 1.14.3 and pandas 0.23.0. Oh sorry about that, I have 12 assets in my full example, posted link to full code if interested.

Comment: @KenSyme I see that it worked for me also, the issue comes in a lates stage I realised, will post.

Comment: Instead of telling us "where the problems start to arise" give us a specific line of code that doesn't work, and what you think the result should be.

Comment: I have posted the whole error, since I believe it's deeply in the data-structure and believe that it can't be fixed only be changing one line of code. But I could be completly wrong as I often am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your function with the parameters in the wrong order. Swap the first two and it works fine:

```
display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate)
```

Comment: I didn't even come to think of that, feel ashamed but you just solved a problem I have had for 2 days. Thank you for lending me your attention to detail and time!